# Microk8s remote with kubectl: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Tags: security, kubernetes, kubectl, credentials, microk8s

I'm trying to connect to microk8s cluster from remote host using kubectl

```
kubectl config view
```

result:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://ip:16443
  name: microk8s-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: microk8s-cluster
    user: microk8s-admin
  name: microk8s
current-context: microk8s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: microk8s-admin
  user:
    password: password
    username: username
```

Credentials like ip, username, password I got using following command on server:

```
sudo microk8s.config
```

result:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: *certificate-data*
    server: https://**ip**:16443
  name: microk8s-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: microk8s-cluster
    user: **user**
  name: microk8s
current-context: microk8s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    token: **password**
```

But if I use

```
kubectl get node
```

I got an error: error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

Comment: Can you add verbosity `-v=9` into `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/kube-apiserver` and restart `mikrok8s` for more logs and information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using username/password for kubectl user I should use just a token from microk8s.config

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanted a more universal (but sometimes redundant) step-by-step version of the accepted answer (duly upvoted):

1. (re)generate k8s config file (which OP already did):

```bash
$ mkdir -p ~/.kube
$ [sudo] microk8s config > ~/.kube/config
```

2. get the k8s API token from the config file (caution: better preserve it more permanently elsewhere, as in kube config it won't survive next logout):

```bash
$ KUBE_TOKEN=$(cat ~/.kube/config | grep token | awk -F":" '{print $2}' | xargs) 
# plus:
$ echo $KUBE_TOKEN > ~/.kube/kube-token # recommended
```

3. login to the remote k8s API server:

```bash
$ kubectl get nodes --token=$KUBE_TOKEN
# or:
$ kubectl get nodes --token=$(cat ~/.kube/kube-token) # recommended
```

If all of the above fails, you may also try to explicitly login using *oc Client Tools* (a `kubectl` drop-in replacement from OKD), which does have the `login` verb (and is more robust to local config file obfuscation/corruption, as it will re-create the file for you locally, assuming you had the token saved elsewhere):

```bash
$ oc login --token=$(cat ~/.kube/kube-token) --server=localhost:16443
```